# Can I use some adjective instead of prepositional phrases like 'of both sexes'?

Tags: word-request, word-formation

Would 'both-sex' or 'both-sexes' be okay (like 'both-sex contestants/team etc.')? Some other compound adjectives? You can, for example, say 'two-faced' instead of 'with two faces'. I need something similar for 'of both sexes'. I'm afraid that if I make something up myself, it wouldn't sound natural.

Comment: '*two-faced*' doesn't usually mean actually '*having two faces*'. It's a slight that someone is [duplicitous](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/two-faced). '*Both-sex contestants*' also makes me think that each contestant is both Male and Female at the same time.

Comment: @Smock What's your alternative?

Comment: If I had one I'd put it as an answer. As it is, @Michel's answer of mixed and Kate's comment of unisex seem fairly good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know in some sports the term 'mixed' is used for both males/females.

And a(nother) typical word for sexes is gender, so you possibly mixed-gender would be ok to use too. Or mixed-sexes (although I cannot recall I ever read this word).

Comment: _Unisex_ is used of clothing suitable for both.

Comment: Or, say, 'with many children'. Can I say 'a many-child mother' or something like that?

Comment: I never heard that expression before (many-xxx yyy)

Comment: What could be used instead?

Comment: mother with many children? Or Mother with multiple children. Gender does not apply here (can be both sons and daughters).

Comment: My question is about substituting prepositional phrases with adjectives